# Spring ConditionalOnProperty for external properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, configuration

It seems `ConditionalOnProperty` only works for properties within the classpath like `application.properties` in the resources folder. I need a property that an end-user can turn on and off via an external property. An example is extremely simple:

Configuration class reads the external properties. `Sys.out` to show it's reading the file properly.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("file:/Users/end.user/MyApp/config/MyApp.properties")
public class PropertyConfigurer {
    @Value("${featureOne}")
    private String featureOne;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("FeatureOne : " + featureOne);
    }
}
```

Feature class, this component class will be put in the application context to be able to be used if the property is enabled via `ConditionalOnProperty`, otherwise the component is never instantiated.

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="featureOne", havingValue = "true")
public class FeatureOne {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Feature initialized");
    }
}
```

As you can imagine I am never seeing "Feature initialized" due to the "featureOne" property not being available to the spring context until after this class has been constructed. If there was some way to force the properties from `@PropertySource` to be available to the spring context upon class instantiation. Or any other way? I also tried `@DependsOn` the `PropertyConfigurer` from `FeatureOne` but that interestingly didn't work either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It seems ConditionalOnProperty only works for properties within the
>   classpath like application.properties in the resources folder.

Not exactly. It also works with external files, provided that they are specified as program arguments during running with `spring.config.location` option.

```
--spring.config.location=file:/Users/end.user/MyApp/config/MyApp.properties
```

The problem is `@PropertySource` is being read by `org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser::processPropertySource` method.  And `@ConditionalOnProperty` is being validated at `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition::getMatchOutcome` method.
If you were to put a debug at these two places, you will find that getMatchOutcome is executed first and then processPropertySource. And hence your condition doesn't work with `@PropertySource`.

But if you were to run your application as `java -jar abc.jar --spring.config.location=file:/Users/end.user/MyApp/config/MyApp.properties`, then these properties are added to context.environment and hence `@ConditionalOnProperty` works.

> If there was some way to force the properties from @PropertySource to
>   be available to the spring context upon class instantiation

I am not sure if there is any way to do this. But given your requirement (I need a property that an end-user can turn on and off via an external property), using `spring.config.location` would be a prudent choice.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is quite old, however, I would like to add my findings here for this issue in case it helps someone facing this problem.

we were on spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE and at least for that version (may be for higher versions also)  the property value from external properties file i.e. **@PropertySource**, for **@ConditionalOnProperty** works if we have the **@PropertySource**("your/properties/file/path") annotation is on the main class or on a configuration class in the **BOOT-INF/classes** which is either imported or componentscanned by the main class.
If the same javaconfig class resides in a jar within BOOT-INF/lib, then it doesn't work.

P.S. we recently migrated from spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE to spring boot 2.7.12 and it still works.